# Validate Date Value before converting in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

We have Dates stored as packed fields in our DB2 tables.  I am able to convert these to a valid DB2 DATE field, but sometimes the source contains an invalid date value such as 20130431 - only 30 days in April.  I know that wwhen the date supplied to DATE function is invalid, the SQLCODE returned is 
-181.  Do I have to write a function to check for the SQLCODE inorder to validate or can I do something in a CASE statement?

Comment: I can kind of imagine the first couple levels of a very ugly nested/compound `CASE` structure that converted the numeric value to `CHAR` and maybe used `LAST_DAY()` with the year and month substrings to get a day number to compare against the low-order characters, after checking the month digits to ensure the range '01' to '12'. By the time the depth got that far, a UDF would prove its worth. The problem arises mostly because SQL wouldn't have allowed an invalid date to be written into a `DATE` column in the first place; it doesn't expect to read invalid values.

Comment: I'm sure you are correct, however, as I stated, these are defined as packed decimal, not Date.

Comment: I put a potentially similar function under [How to validate date in String format which is a varchar data type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168792/db2-how-to-validate-date-in-string-format-which-is-a-varchar-data-type/22752980#22752980). Might be easy to adapt the structure for a DECIMAL value.

Comment: There is an example of an IS_DATE function for Db2 LUW here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297100/valid-date-verification-in-sql/52298712#52298712