# DB2: How to validate date in String format which is a varchar data type

Tags: sql, database, validation, db2

I need to know wheather a data in a column of type varchar is in correct date format or not .
I have to do the same in DB2.

I have done this in java by using SimpleDateFormat() and Date.Parse() functions with the help of Exception handling .

I'm posting my java code to validate a string to date

```
private boolean isValidDate(String date) {
    try{
        DateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        d.setLenient(false);
        d.parse(date);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

but now i have to do the same in **DB2 data base**.Can i use any functions or procederes in DB2

my data in table column is like this..

20140231

20000101

.

.

.

yyyyMMdd

and **column type is varchar**

Comment: look at my update answer and with examples...

Comment: There is an IS_DATE user defined function here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297100/valid-date-verification-in-sql/52298712#52298712 that can check if an input is a valid date

Answer (score 1):

**My style of display the date:**

```
 try
     {
 Date dob = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("date"));
     user.setDate(date);
     }
       catch(ParseException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

**note: if you should give like as yyyy-MMM-dd or MM/dd/yyyy**

**your programs as:**

```
private boolean isValidDate(String date) 
{
try
{
DateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy").parse(request.getParameter("date"));
        d.setLenient(false);
        d.parse(date);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

***Timestamp to varchar:***

**timestamp-expression**

An expression that returns a value that must be a DATE or TIMESTAMP, or a valid string representation of a date or timestamp that is not a CLOB or DBCLOB.

If the argument is a string, the format-string argument must also be specified.

In a Unicode database, if a supplied argument is a graphic string representation of a data, time, or timestamp, it is first converted to a character string before evaluating the function.

If timestamp-expression is a DATE or a valid string representation of a date, it is first converted to a TIMESTAMP(0) value, assuming a time of exactly midnight (00.00.00).

For the valid formats of string representations of datetime values, see "String representations of datetime values" in "Datetime values".

**format-string**

The expression must return a value that is a built-in CHAR, VARCHAR, numeric, or datetime data type.

If the value is not a CHAR or VARCHAR data type, it is implicitly cast to VARCHAR before evaluating the function.

In a Unicode database, if the supplied argument is a GRAPHIC or VARGRAPHIC data type, it is first converted to VARCHAR before evaluating the function. The actual length must not be greater than 254 bytes (SQLSTATE 22007).

The value is a template for how timestamp-expression is to be formatted.

A valid format-string must contain a combination of the format elements listed below (SQLSTATE 22007).

Two format elements can optionally be separated by one or more of the following separator characters:

```
minus sign (-)
period (.)
slash (/)
comma (,)
apostrophe (')
semi-colon (;)
colon (:)
blank ( )
```

note:

[click 1](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001384522.htm)

[click2](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html)

***UPDATE:***

*sample code 1: Convert the current date to YYYYMM format*

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m');
```

**o/p:  # 201403**

*sample code 2: Convert the current date to YYYYMM format*

```
 SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMM') FROM jmail;
```

**o/p  # 201403**

[image: details of date_format]

sample:

```
No | MySQL                         |      DB2                           |SampleOutput

1  | DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d) | VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')| 2013-02-14

2  | DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d/%m/%y')| VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE,'DD/MM/RR')  |  14/02/13
```

Comment: Except he needs to write this in DB2, probably not Java (although some versions do allow external languages for functions).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, goto this site:http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0007110.html

Comment: That's going the wrong direction.  He alreadt has the string, he wants to find out if it's a date.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, I've give the useful comments (+1 usfulcomments) for your first comment, because look at my brief explanation update.

Comment: None of this helps.  He's trying to from a string to a date/timestamp.  If all of his data is valid, he can just convert it to the relevant type.  If he has data which represents invalid dates (say `2014-02-29`), they can't be converted, and will cause the db to throw an exception.  Last I knew, DB2 didn't have a date-checking function, it was up to the developer to use the proper type.  I suppose one way to check would be to generate all valid dates and check if the data is not in that set...but instead your answer is mostly just the text of how to _format_, which is largely irrelevant.

Comment: @Clock, oh, i think you didn't see the post clearly, look at this(@Itachiuchiha, source:in the first line of this post) data in a column of type **varchar is in correct date format or not.**

Comment: @jmail thanks for the post but what i need is a function / procrdure in **DB2** that takes varchar as argument and check wheather given argument is a valid date or not .

EG: isValiddate('20140233') --> should return false 
and this should be done in DB2 only i gave the java Example for better understanding of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what "flavor" of DB2 is needed. With DB2 for i, I'd probably create a function to do the test and return an indication of success or failure. Here's an example that works for me:

```
DROP SPECIFIC FUNCTION SQLEXAMPLE.CHKVCDATE ; 

SET PATH "QSYS","QSYS2","SYSPROC","SYSIBMADM","SQLEXAMPLE" ; 

CREATE FUNCTION SQLEXAMPLE.CHKVCDATE ( 
    VCDATE VARCHAR(20) ) 
    RETURNS INTEGER   
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    SPECIFIC SQLEXAMPLE.CHKVCDATE 
    DETERMINISTIC 
    CONTAINS SQL 
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT 
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
    NOT FENCED 
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
    ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
    COMMIT = *CHG , 
    CLOSQLCSR = *ENDMOD , 
    DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
    DFTRDBCOL = *NONE , 
    DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
    DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
    SRTSEQ = *HEX   

    BEGIN ATOMIC 

DECLARE CHKDATE DATE ; 
DECLARE VALIDDATE INT ; 

DECLARE NOT_VALID CONDITION FOR '22007' ; 
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT_VALID 
    SET VALIDDATE = -1 ; 

SET VALIDDATE = 0 ; 

VALUES ( VCDATE ) INTO CHKDATE ; 

RETURN VALIDDATE ; 

END  ; 

COMMENT ON SPECIFIC FUNCTION SQLEXAMPLE.CHKVCDATE 
    IS 'Check VARCHAR for valid date' ;
```

Any properties or other details that don't fit your particular DB2 can be removed or changed. The size of the `VCDATE VARCHAR` parm might need adjustment, and the `RETURN` value can be whatever you need. The function might be useful in a `WHERE` clause.

I can invoke it like this:

```
select sqlexample.chkvcdate('2014-02-29'), sqlexample.chkvcdate('2014-02-28') from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

The first will return ( -1 ) for the invalid value, and the second will return ( 0 ) for valid.