# Valid date verification in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have a column that holds `LossDate` in the format of (`yyyymmdd`). I need to verify that if the month ends in 30 days, then no loss was reported with a loss date of 31. I have millions of records. Help will be highly appreciated.

```
LossDate
--------
20120128
20150520
20180631
```

Query should return the last invalid record because 200806 ends in 30 days.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: it's numeric in db2

Comment: DB2 has a `LAST_DAY()` function (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_lastday.html) that will let you determine if your `LossDate` is equal to the `LAST_DAY` of the month. But because it's `numeric`, I think you'll have to convert it to an actual date or a string that properly represents the date. DB2 treats numeric entities different than string entities, as it relates to "dates", so 20180631 may not be the same as '20180631'. Maybe use `TO_CHAR(LossDate)` or `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(TO_CHAR(LossDate),'YYYYMMDD')`.

Comment: But why do you have a "date" value of  `20180631`? That's not a valid date anyway? So why would you be reporting a loss on a date after the last day of the month? And what about February?

Comment: Correct, old system, and data has been entered incorrectly as there's no trigger. so we're in a process of cleansing invalid data.

Comment: Are you changing the invalid data or fixing the bad date?

Comment: If you're fixing bad data, I'd recommend also fixing the data structure so that these dates are stored as actual date objects instead of integers. That said, it might be easiest to create a new date-type column and copy the '`LossDate` values that can be properly converted to a date. Then it will be easy to identify the rows with invalid `LossDate`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific question, the following will return bad rows:

```
select * 
from table 
where substr(lossdate,5,2) in ('04','06','09','11')
    and substr(lossdate,7,2) > '30'
```

Depending on your input interface, you may need to repeat that for months with 31 days that show values greater than 31.

```
select * 
from table 
where substr(lossdate,5,2) in ('01','03','07','08','10','12')  
    and substr(lossdate,7,2) > '31'
```

Feb is a little trickier.  Start incrementally, identifying all February entries with more than 29 days, you can get rid of/fix those immediately.

```
select * 
from table 
where substr(lossdate,5,2) = '02' 
    and substr(lossdate,7,2) > '29'
```

Then you need to repeat this for the remaining rows with Feb dates greater than 28 and aren't a leap year.  In the last 100 years, any year divisible by 4 is a leap year, so you can identify the remainder with this (assuming you corrected/deleted the bad Feb entries you already found):

```
select * 
from table 
where substr(lossdate,5,2) = '02' 
    and mod(substr(lossdate,1,4),4)) <> 0 
    and substr(lossdate,7,2) > '28'
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Just a word of caution, if you are working with millions of rows, I'm not sure how this will perform.

Comment: It's going to tablescan and take a bit of cpu to perform all that mod() and substr().  To avoid 4 distinct scans, I'd OR the WHERE conditions together.

Comment: (And to avoid your query locking others out, perhaps run it WITH UR.)

Answer (score 3):

You could create an ISDATE a function such below and then use it in a query such as `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DB_IS_DATE(LOSSDATE) = 0` to find all your invalid dates

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IS_DATE(YYYYMMDD INTEGER)
RETURNS SMALLINT
LANGUAGE SQL CONTAINS SQL DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION
RETURN
  CASE
    WHEN YYYYMMDD/10000 BETWEEN 1 AND 9999
    AND(    ( MOD(YYYYMMDD/100, 100) IN (1,3,5,7,8,10,12) AND MOD(YYYYMMDD,100) BETWEEN 1 AND 31 )  -- Jan,Mar,May,Jul,Aug,Oct,Dec have 31 days
         OR ( MOD(YYYYMMDD/100, 100) IN (4,6,9,11)        AND MOD(YYYYMMDD,100) BETWEEN 1 AND 30 )  -- Apr,Jun,Sep,Nov             have 30 days
         OR ( MOD(YYYYMMDD/100, 100) = 2                  AND MOD(YYYYMMDD,100) BETWEEN 1 AND 28 )  -- Feb has 28 days
         OR ( MOD(YYYYMMDD/100, 100) = 2                  AND MOD(YYYYMMDD,100) BETWEEN 1 AND 29    --   unless is a leap year. i.e.
              AND ( ( MOD(YYYYMMDD/10000,4) = 0 AND MOD(YYYYMMDD/10000,100) <> 0)                   --   year is divisable by 4 but not 100
                OR  MOD(YYYYMMDD/10000,400) = 0 )                                                   --     or year is divisable by 400
            )       
         )
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
```

If you are using Db2 Warehouse you could return a `BOOLEAN` from the function. E.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IS_DATE(YYYYMMDD INTEGER)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE SQL CONTAINS SQL DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION
RETURN
        YYYYMMDD/10000 BETWEEN 1 AND 9999
    AND(    ( MOD(YYYYMMDD/100, 100) IN (1,3,5,7,8,10,12) AND MOD(YYYYMMDD,100) BETWEEN 1 AND 31 )  -- Jan,Mar,May,Jul,Aug,Oct,Dec have 31 days
         OR ( MOD(YYYYMMDD/100, 100) IN (4,6,9,11)        AND MOD(YYYYMMDD,100) BETWEEN 1 AND 30 )  -- Apr,Jun,Sep,Nov             have 30 days
         OR ( MOD(YYYYMMDD/100, 100) = 2                  AND MOD(YYYYMMDD,100) BETWEEN 1 AND 28 )  -- Feb has 28 days
         OR ( MOD(YYYYMMDD/100, 100) = 2                  AND MOD(YYYYMMDD,100) BETWEEN 1 AND 29    --   unless is a leap year. i.e.
              AND ( ( MOD(YYYYMMDD/10000,4) = 0 AND MOD(YYYYMMDD/10000,100) <> 0)                   --   year is divisable by 4 but not 100
                OR  MOD(YYYYMMDD/10000,400) = 0 )                                                   --     or year is divisable by 400
            )       
         )
```

The function can be used to convert the input to a DATE if it is a valid date. E.g.

```
SELECT i, IS_DATE(i) AS IS_DATE
,      CASE WHEN IS_DATE(i) = 1 THEN DATE(TO_DATE(DIGITS(DECIMAL(i,8,0)),'YYYYMMDD')) END AS DATE
FROM TABLE(VALUES(-999),(0),(1),(00010101),(99991231),(20180101),(20180228),(20160229),(20180229),(20000229),(19000229)) as D(i)
```

which returns

```
 I        IS_DATE DATE
 -------- ------- ----------
     -999       0 NULL
        0       0 NULL
        1       0 NULL
    10101       1 0001-01-01
 99991231       1 9999-12-31
 20180101       1 2018-01-01
 20180228       1 2018-02-28
 20160229       1 2016-02-29
 20180229       0 NULL
 20000229       1 2000-02-29
 19000229       0 NULL
```

The function will also accept strings of "YYYYMMDD" format. Db2 will cast the string to an integer for you.
If you have a string of e.g. "YYYY-MM-DD" format, you could create a character version of the function that calls the above function such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IS_DATE(YYYYMMDD VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE SQL CONTAINS SQL DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION
RETURN
   CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(YYYYMMDD,'[0-9]{4}?-[0-9]{2}?-[0-9]{2}?') = 1 
        THEN IS_DATE(INTEGER(REPLACE(YYYYMMDD,'-',''))) ELSE 0 END
```

Another option is to create a UDF that uses in-built Db2 functions, but catches any error that they might generate. E.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IS_DATE(input VARCHAR(32), format VARCHAR(32)) 
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE SQL CONTAINS SQL DETERMINISTIC ALLOW PARALLEL NO EXTERNAL ACTION
BEGIN 
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
    RETURN 0;
  RETURN CASE WHEN TO_DATE(input, format) >= '0001-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
END
@
```

Comment: I made a few edits to my post. The one above should be the final version (I hope)