# DB2 SQL capturing errors on date formating

Tags: sql, db2-400

If I get an error on a DB2 SQL date conversion, what syntax can I use to capture/report on the 
    error, while allowing job to continue. eg: write to file or log or print file?

example:
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(MYDATE))  Where MYDATE = '20200132'

error message:

```
 Message . . . . :   Expression not valid using format string specified      
   for TIMESTAMP_FORMAT.                                                     
 Cause . . . . . :   Argument 1 of the TIMESTAMP_FORMAT function can not     
   be interpreted using the format string specified in argument 2 for        
   one of the following reasons:                                             
    -- The string expression is too short or too long.                       
    -- The string expression does not conform to the template specified      
       in the format string.                                                 
    -- Too many digits were specified in the string expression for the       
       corresponding format element in the format string.                    
    -- A value in the string expression is not valid for the                 
       corresponding format element in the format string.                    
 Recovery  . . . :   Specify a valid format string for the function. Try
```

Comment: Is there any chance you can scrub your data before running your DB2 code?

Comment: good idea, but how can I use SQL to identify bad data?

Comment: good discussion here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297100/valid-date-verification-in-sql/52298712#52298712

Answer (score 0):

You can use a User Defined Function (UDF) to handle the conversion and catch errors.

returning NULL when invalid, or perhaps for 9999999-->9999-12-31.

You can build or own or find some example code. For Db2 for IBM i specifically, there's an open source library named [iDate](http://think400.dk/downloads.htm) by Alan Campin used by many.